# jquery click not work on select tag in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, select, click

I have a problem with jquery click in my code. my code this is:

```
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $("#hide").click(function(){
            $(".mapg").hide();
          });
          $("#show").click(function(){
            $(".mapg").show();
          });
        });
    </script>

    <select name="showmapg" id="showmapg" class="form-control" required>
        <option value="0">Select</option>
        <option id="show" value="1">Yes</option>
        <option id="hide" value="2">No</option>
    </select>

    <p class="mapg" style="display: none;">Hello</p>
```

my code work in firefox but it's not work in chrome. how can do it?

Answer (score 3):

You should register your click event to select element itself and not to its options..

Making it as simple as possible. Try this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
          $("#showmapg").change(function(){ // or .click(function(){
             if(this.value == 2) {
                $(".mapg").hide();
             }else{ //use else if , if you want to nothing to happen on select option
              $(".mapg").show();
             }
          });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="showmapg" id="showmapg" class="form-control" required>
        <option value="0">Select</option>
        <option id="show" value="1">Yes</option>
        <option id="hide" value="2">No</option>
    </select>

    <p class="mapg" style="display: none;">Hello</p>
```

Comment: yup i agree, that is why i have a comment added there, anyways let me update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

your code would be:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#showmapg").change(function(){
        if($(this).val()==1){
          $('.mapg').show();
        }
        else if($(this).val()==2){
          $('.mapg').hide();
        }
      });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Click event is not valid for option elements. Use `.change()` event of select to show/hide element:

```
$('#showmapg').change(function(){
  if($(this).val()=="1")
    $(".mapg").show();
  else
    $(".mapg").hide();
 });
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ss9kpv0n/)**